# How to make a swf file created in InDesign full screen?

Tags: flash, adobe-indesign

I have created a swf file in InDesign, but now it is not full screen. Even if I import it into Flash Professional doesn't it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is relative to InDesign CS5, I don't know other versions.

When I want to make a full screen swf presentation in InDesign I follow these steps:

- build a document with the correct screen resolution (for example 1024x768 is a good resolution because it's a common projectors resolution)
- export the swf including the HTML
- open the HTML and remove margins and scrollbars with CSS
- open with your browser and enable the full screen mode, usually F11

to remove scrollbars and margin change the body declaration with this:

```
<body style="margin:0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #000000;">
```

I don't know other way.